# What is the best way for a user to place a 3D Holographic model on top of its real object in AR?

Tags: augmented-reality

We are working on an augmented reality app with the Hololens glasses.

We have a "real" object, let's say a Rubik's cube, and we loaded its 3D model (a cube) into the Hololens.

We want to be able to put the Hologram (the cube) at the same position of the Rubik's cube, to cover it.

We have been thinking about recognizing with the Hololens's camera the Rubik's cube, then place the cube where it's being recognized, but this isn't working well.

We have been thinking about putting the cube in front of the eyes of the user but his depth perception will be altered.

What is the best way for the user to place the cube on top of the real Rubik's cube?

Comment: The only way I can think of is by first recognizing the real cube, what trouble are you having with that? Can't you use some kind of marker sticker? Or maybe the real cube should have a static placement at all times?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest using some introductory content / audio to describe what you want to do.

The thing with Hololens is that there's no 'home page' for the apps, and it's all new interactions that aren't yet instinctive to users (pinch to zoom is intuitive on mobiles now, but wasn't when it first came out - people had to learn it so that it became instinctive). So, you can use the features of HoloLens to 'on-board' the user in how to use the app and the device itself.

So, a little audio introduction to the task, something like:

> *"Locate the Rubiks Cube on the table infront of you and then place this virtual cube over the top..."*.

You could also provide a little visual animation showing what you need the user to do.

The great thing about Hololens is that it's not just a visual experience - don't restrict the information to pure visual ones.